# MYSQL+Load data INFILE + Check fields

Tags: mysql, file, csv

I have two questions regarding the `MYSQL LOAD DATA FILE` function:

**1)** How can I make sure all fields in the `data file` are set?

<del>**2)** Can I make it skip the first row of the `data file`?</del>

The code I am currently working with:

```
$dbq    = "field1,field2,field3,field4";
$query  = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$targetPath' INTO TABLE $db FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ($dbq)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if(!$result){
    echo($mysqli->error+".");
    exit();
} else{
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

And the `data file` is a `.csv` file:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To skip a line, change your load string to:

```
$query  = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$targetPath' INTO TABLE $db FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' IGNORE 1 LINES ($dbq)";
```

Comment: This works :) thanks! I am gonna leave the question open thou, because i still need to check if all fields are set or not!